# is bigO different in these cases?

Tags: java, big-o

In these two different codes (doing same thing), is the bigO different. the O(1) statement is changed but the for-loops stay same i.e. same number of runs?

```
 for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
         b+=i+i 
    } 
  }
```

And,

```
     for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int k = i+i;
        for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
             b+=k;
        } 
      }
```

isnt both the codes running quadratic times??

Comment: I assume it should be `for (j=0;j<i;j++) {` in second one?

Comment: oops! yup.. thanks.. what about now??

Comment: Both are quadratic

Answer (score 1):

They have the same `O(n^2)` complexity.

Both have the same structure:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    // some constant amount of steps (without changing i or n), say p steps
    for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
         // another constant amount of steps (without changing i or j), say q steps
    } 
}
```

In order to count overall complexity, let's count the steps one-by-one:

```
i = 0, so p steps on this stage
i = 1, j from 0 to 0, so (p + q) steps on this stage
...
i = k, j from 0 to k-1, so (p + q*k) steps on this stage
...
i = n-1, j from 0 to n-1, so (p + q*(n-1)) steps on this stage
```

In total, `p*n + q*n*(n-1)/2` steps, or `O(n^2)` in BigO notation